# Python parse HTML with escape characters

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, escaping, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape data from a website, but the data table is rendered by JavaScript. Instead of using a tool like Selenium to generate the page and run the script, I have instead found the script tag where the data is stored and am trying to pull the data directly from there.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://www.etf.com/SPY'

result = requests.get(url)

c = result.content
html = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')

script = html.find_all('script')[-22]   #this is the script tag that has the data

script = script.contents

js = script[0]
data = js[31:-2]  #data is the json/dict which has the data
```

This is a snippet of what the contents of data looks like:

[image]

```
s = json.loads(data)

s = s['etf_report_from_api']['modalInfoToActive']['top10Holdings']['data']

s = s[13:-2]
```

Here is a snippet of what s looks like:

[image]

At this point the content is looking more like HTML, but it seems like the escape characters have not been unescaped properly

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
```

Here is the output of the parser. it seems to be able to recognize certain tags but is identifying others as data due to the formatting issue.

[image]

This data is essentially an HTML table, but how can I properly decode/parse it to extract the data contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you simply need to unescape `"` and `/` values in your string `s`, and then you can successfully parse the markup with `bs4`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.replace(r"\"", '"').replace(r"\/", "/"), "html.parser")

for row in soup.find_all("tr"):
    name, value = row.find_all("td")
    print(f"{name.text}\t{value.text}")
```

Result:

```
Microsoft Corporation   3.55%
Apple Inc.  3.31%
Amazon.com, Inc.    3.11%
Facebook, Inc. Class A  1.76%
Berkshire Hathaway Inc. Class B 1.76%
...
```